# How to know that user has pressed backspace button in Entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have 4 Entry Fields.. So I want that if Users delete all the text in any Entry and then again press backspace then I should take him to previous Entry..

HandleTextChanged is not getting Called when there is nothing in Entry and user is pressing Backspace.

Please guide me How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I achieved it using Renderers.

Sample Code.

iOS renderes

```
 public class UIBackwardsTextField : UITextField
{
    // A delegate type for hooking up change notifications.
    public delegate void DeleteBackwardEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the
    // elements of the list change.
    public event DeleteBackwardEventHandler OnDeleteBackward;


    public void OnDeleteBackwardPressed()
    {
        if (OnDeleteBackward != null)
        {
            OnDeleteBackward(null, null);
        }
    }

    public UIBackwardsTextField()
    {
        BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
        ClipsToBounds = true;
    }

    public override void DeleteBackward()
    {
        base.DeleteBackward();
        OnDeleteBackwardPressed();
    }
}
public class OTPCustomEntryRenderer_ios : EntryRenderer, IUITextFieldDelegate
{
    IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        if (Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var entry = (OTPCustomEntry)Element;
        var textField = new UIBackwardsTextField();

        textField.EditingChanged += OnEditingChanged;
        textField.OnDeleteBackward += (sender, a) =>
        {
            entry.OnBackspacePressed();
        };

        SetNativeControl(textField);

        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    void OnEditingChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Entry.TextProperty, Control.Text);
    }

}
```

Android Renderes

```
 public class OTPCustomEntryRenderer_android : EntryRenderer
{
    public OTPCustomEntryRenderer_android(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Del)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Control.Text))
                {
                    var entry = (OTPCustomEntry)Element;
                    entry.OnBackspacePressed();
                }
            }
        }
        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }

    protected override void
    OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

}
```

CustomEntry Class in Xamarin Forms

```
public class OTPCustomEntry : Entry
{
    public delegate void BackspaceEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event BackspaceEventHandler OnBackspace;

    public OTPCustomEntry()
    {

    }

    public void OnBackspacePressed()
    {
        if (OnBackspace != null)
        {
            OnBackspace(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

In Your XAML

```
<local:OTPCustomEntry x:Name="Entry" ReturnType="Next" TextChanged="Handle_Entry1_TextChanged"
                                      />
```

And Your C# code add Listner

```
Entry.OnBackspace += EntryBackspaceEventHandler;


    public void EntryBackspaceEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

}

And here it how You can use in Your Code

Comment: FYI: On Android this will not always work when using soft input (in an emulator it does work or a device with a hardware keyboard). Due to the various APIs handling of IME soft inputs this works on older APIs but on newer ones it will not produce events depending upon how the OEM implemented ASOP and also varies from soft input keyboard to keyboard....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Everything worked fine on Android, but on iOS I had problems with other events, in my case specifically with Focus / Unfocus. With your iOS renderer code, events like focus / out of focus will never be raised.

Based on the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view you have to pay attention and prevent memory leaks.

`ExtendedEntry`... is my custom Entry implementation

This is my iOS Renderer implementation:

```
using System;
using Emcoding.iOS.Renderers;
using Emcoding.Renderers;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedEntry), typeof(ExtendedEntryRenderer))]
namespace Emcoding.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class UIBackwardsTextField : UITextField
    {
        // A delegate type for hooking up change notifications.
        public delegate void DeleteBackwardEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

        // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the
        // elements of the list change.
        public event DeleteBackwardEventHandler OnDeleteBackward;
        
        public void OnDeleteBackwardPressed()
        {
            OnDeleteBackward?.Invoke(null, null);
        }
        public override void DeleteBackward()
        {
            base.DeleteBackward();
            OnDeleteBackwardPressed();
        }
    }
    
    public class ExtendedEntryRenderer : ViewRenderer<ExtendedEntry, UIBackwardsTextField>, 
IUITextFieldDelegate
    {
        private UIBackwardsTextField _uiBackwardsTextField;
        
        private IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ExtendedEntry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
                _uiBackwardsTextField.EditingChanged -= OnEditingChanged;
                _uiBackwardsTextField.OnDeleteBackward -= OnDeleteBackward;
                _uiBackwardsTextField.TouchDown -= OnFocused;
                _uiBackwardsTextField.Ended -= OnUnfocused;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    // Instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with
                    // the SetNativeControl method
                    
                    _uiBackwardsTextField = new UIBackwardsTextField
                    {
                        // Put your UiTextField customization here...
                    };

                    SetNativeControl(_uiBackwardsTextField);
                }
               
                // Events
                _uiBackwardsTextField.EditingChanged += OnEditingChanged;
                _uiBackwardsTextField.OnDeleteBackward += OnDeleteBackward;
                _uiBackwardsTextField.TouchDown += OnFocused;
                _uiBackwardsTextField.Ended += OnUnfocused;
            }
        }

        private void OnDeleteBackward(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Element.OnBackspacePressed();
        }

        private void OnEditingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Entry.TextProperty, Control.Text);
        }

        private void OnFocused(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Entry.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);
        }        
        
        private void OnUnfocused(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Entry.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
        }
    }
}
```